# After upgrading from bootstrap3.3.6 to 4.0 Beta layout issue alignment issue

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

In my layout page I have Header content and footer. When I was using bootstrap 3.3.6 the elements in the page was perfectly aligned.

Recently I upgraded bootstrap to 4.0.0 beta and the alignment of my layout page has gone bonkers

Below i have posted the issue in jsfiddle

The header and the content is overlapping and wrapping in next line.

In actuality it should be header row then in next row(without padding or margin) there should be two deparment image with Depatment Name in middle next row should have rendered body from views then footer.

Any help will be appreciated.

[Here is the link for issue](http://jsfiddle.net/hRpAw/283/)

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCustom">
        <i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg py-1 text-white"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse col-md-12" id="navbarCustom">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color:white;">
                                Review Queue
                            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="color:white;">
              <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="right:0; left: auto; top: 50px;">
              <li>
                Logged In @User.Identity.Name
              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li>
                <a href="/Account/Logout"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar">
          <div style="width:100%; background-color: #f8f8f8; border-color: #e7e7e7; background-repeat: repeat-x; border-radius: 4px; height:125px;">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
              <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="#" title="NYC Logo">
                  <img src="http://www.altpress.com/images/uploads/news/Hello_Kitty.jpg" alt="Logo1" class="img-rounded" style="height:4em; width: 4em; vertical-align:middle; text-align: center;" />
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
              <div style="text-align : center">
                <h3>My Company's Name</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
              <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="#" title="My Department">
                  <img src="http://www.altpress.com/images/uploads/news/Hello_Kitty.jpg" alt="Logo2" class="img-rounded" style="height:4em; width: 4em; vertical-align:middle; text-align: center;"/>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid body-content">
        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
          @RenderBody()
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
     <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="float-left">
          <p style="font-style:normal; color:#9c9c9c;text-align:left; vertical-align:middle;">&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: The change from 3.* to 4.* means that the library was totally recreated. So, you can not just update like that. Grid scheme has different sizes, new elements.
Check the new version's change log, before you do any update.
http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2017/08/10/bootstrap-4-beta/

Comment: I did read the document. I have all the required references in my application. I am not sure what changes to make in layout page esp in class.